# JMeter response assertion validation

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing

I have request something similar to the below each using first 3 characters of a name, Ex: `WAL`.

It results in 3 responses:

```
<Name>
<firstname>WALLER</firstname>
<firstname>WALTER</firstname>
<firstname>WALMER</firstname>
```

I have to include response assertion to validate the above 3 names:

Note: this is dynamic. For the above results, it is 3
For some it might fetch 1, 2, 4 etc. Could anyone please tell me how to validate this?

Comment: You can validate with the help of regular expression extractor and confirm.

Comment: I have to validate multiple attrbutes. In the above scenario if search yields multiple names with address details like address line, line2,city,zip code etc. How to validate this

Answer (score 1):

I can see 2 options:

1. You use the same test against the same test data, it means that you will be getting the same responses each time. This is preferred way of designing your test as it needs to be [**repeatable**](http://defragdev.com/blog/?p=718) otherwise even if you detect an issue and cannot reproduce it by running the same test this test doesn't make a lot of sense.
2. If you cannot afford having static data for some reason you can consider doing some preparation in [setUp Test phase](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) or directly [before the request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors). For example if the system under test makes a database query in order to return search results you can execute the same query using i.e. [JDBC PreProcesor](https://www.blazemeter.com/jdbc-preprocessor) to pre-populate expected data set

---

Also your response looks utterly like [XML](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/) so it might be easier to consider using [XPath Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Assertion) instead of the Response Assertion in order to validate the data.